# Can anyone provide some resource about unit testing of forms in Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, forms, phpunit

How can I test the forms in zend framework?
I have a login form in my zend project, the Login.php is:

```
<?php
class DEMO_Form_Login extends Zend_Form {

    public function init() {
        $this
            ->setMethod('post')
            ->addElementPrefixPaths(array(
                'decorator' => array('DEMO_Decorator' => '../application/decorators'),
            ));

        $this
        ->addElement('text', 'username', array(
            'label' => _T('USERNAME'),
            'required' => true,
            'value' => '',
            'filters'    => array('StringTrim'),
            'decorators' => array('ViewHelper')
            ))
        ->addElement('password', 'password', array(
            'label' => _T('PASSWORD'),
            'required' => true,
            'value' => '',
            'decorators' => array('ViewHelper')
            ))
        ->addElement('submit', 'submit', array(
            'label' => _T('LOG_INTO'),
            'ignore' => true,
            'decorators' => array(
                array('Submit', array('separator'=>'<br />')))  
            ));
    }

}
```

How can I test it? Can anyone provide some resource about it?

Comment: What do you want to test? You dont need to `testAddElementAddsAnElement`, because that's already covered in the ZF Unit Tests.

Comment: here is a cast form Zendcasts.com about testing Zend form http://www.zendcasts.com/unit-testing-zend_form/2010/10/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot think of any resource, but I can give you one example of how I would do it.

So, I would create a FormTestCase class as follows:

```
class FormTestCase extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    private $_form;

    public function setUp() {
        parent::setUp();
    }

}
```

Then each form could be tested as follows:

```
class DemoFormTest extends FormTestCase {

    public function setUp() {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->_form = new My_Form_Demo();
    }

    public function testCorrectData() {
        $mockInputData = array(
            'username' => 'somename',
            'password' => 'somepass',
            'submit' => 'LOG_INTO'
        );

        $this->assertTrue($this->_form->isValid($mockInputData));
    }

     public function testInCorrectData() {
        $mockInputData = array(
            'username' => 'somename',   
            // password not given
            'submit' => 'LOG_INTO'
        );

        $this->assertFalse($this->_form->isValid($mockInputData));
    }

    // some other tests
}
```

In the above example `My_Form_Demo` is [simplified](https://github.com/marcinwol/houseshare/blob/appartments/application/forms/Demo.php) version of your form. I needed to simplify it, because I do not have  your custom decorators and I could not run  the test. The setup that I used for this example, can be seen [here](https://github.com/marcinwol/houseshare/tree/appartments/tests) (along with all my other tests).

Hope this will help you.